# How to remove empty space between bars in Highcharts polar chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Is it possible to remove the empty space between the bars within a Highcharts polar chart, so that it looks like a pie chart? I just want to fill up the whole 360 degrees of the chart without spaces between the "spikes".

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/polar-wind-rose/)

Are there any options for the plot or series parameter?

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        shadow: false,
        groupPadding: 0,
        pointPlacement: 'on'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to add the pointPadding option :

```
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            shadow: false,
            groupPadding: 0,
            pointPadding: 0
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7pddwx6a/